# How to use wildcard in command prompt while executing the pytest test cases

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I have below project structure in Pycharm.

**Project Folder:** PythonTutorial

**Package:** pytestpackage

**Python Files:** test_conftest_demo1.py, test_conftest_demo2.py

I'm trying to run the above 2 python files having almost similar name using pytest from command prompt with the below command. But I'm facing the below issue. Please help me on the same.

**Note:** I'm using windows 10 operating system .

**Command Used:**
py.test -s -v test_conftest_demo*.py

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the `-k` option to specify substring matching.

```
$ pytest -s -v -k "test_conftest_demo"
```